# Priorvalue is not Exported then not allowed to change status to delivered

Tags: formula, validation-rule

The below code is mentioned in formula editor and this is showing

> The formula expression is invalid: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'PRIORVALUE()'. Expected 1, received 2

```
  PRIORVALUE(([Opportunity].Status__c ), "Exported"))
```

Comment: I should think you would be able to look through documentation and find examples on your own by now.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Error You have one Extra `)` at the end . Can you try this.

```
  PRIORVALUE(([Opportunity].Status__c ), "Exported")
```

If Status is picklist field then you have to use `ISPICKVAL()` function as well like below.

```
 ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE([Opportunity].Status__c), 'Exported')
```

As per the updated question your if current values is Exported then only you should be able to change it to Delivered.

Which means the validation should be as below.

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.Status__c,'Delivered'), NOT( ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE(Opportunity.Status__c), 'Exported')))
```

This check if we are changing Status to Delivered and prior value is not Exported it shows the Error

Comment: This is picklist and when i use ispickval this is showing error The formula expression is invalid: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Text).

Comment: Can you edit the question and confirm what should be the output of the formula?

Comment: after exported next status is delivered. so if prior status is not exported then it should not changed to delivered

Comment: Do you need validation rule for this?

Comment: yes, i need this

Comment: Can you edit the Question

Comment: edited question done

Comment: I have updated the answer based on your question now

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for using prior value for picklist fields is-

```
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Field), 'Value')
```

Update your formula as given below-

```
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Opportunity.Status__c), 'Exported')
```